# Drools workbench 7.5.0.Final not able to add some dependency to its package white list

Tags: drools, kie-workbench

Refer attached screenshot to describe the problem.

From the setting I am not able to change "package not Included" to "All Package Included" for artifact package drools-webService and gitLab4-api.

I am running drools work bench on tomcat 7.

[image: link to image for reference]

Answer (score 1):

I explored little more and found that the dependency which I was trying to add was internally using many other dependency. It seems drools workbench was not able to resolve some of them, due to which it was not allowing me to include to white list.

To check my theory I tried to create a separate module in my project which will have only data objects. So that load on drools workbench is minimised. I created jar of module and tried to load it to workbench. Guess what It worked and loaded my data object to my drools project. Now I am able to write/define rules on them. :)

[Refer attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2Hbs.png)